# Is there an infinite vector space over Z/2Z?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm not even sure how to start thinking about this problem... Some help will be appreciated. I'm currently learning linear algebra using Axler's book, and have spent time dealing with just vector spaces over $\mathbb{F}$, which is $\mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{R}$, both of which are infinite fields.

I do see that there can be finite vector spaces over $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, but I'm unsure about the existence of infinite dimensional vector space.

Comment: There are vector spaces of every possible dimension over any field. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_module

Answer (score 4):

How about the additive group of the polynomial ring $k[X]$ for $k=\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$?

Comment: We haven't learned abstract algebra that far to ring... can you explicitly define scalar multiplication in this vector space for clarification? Thanks

Comment: Over $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ scalar multiplication is dead easy: $0v=0$ and $1v=v$ for all $v$ in your vector space.

Comment: Ah I see, if we define [0]v=0 and [1]v=v, then it does make a vector space right?

Comment: By the way, just want to ask can we define multiplication in the same way so that $\mathbb{R}^n$ is also a vector space?

Answer (score 1):

The set of sequences ${\bf u}=(u_n)_{n\geq 0}$ with values in $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ is an infinite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ .

For, let ${\bf e_k}=(\delta_{k,n})_{n\geq 0}$, that is the sequence whose values are all zero, except the one of index $k$, which is $1$.

Then you can show easily that the various ${\bf e_k},k\geq 0$ are linearly independent.

Answer (score 0):

The algebraic closure $k$ of the field $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ can be regarded as a $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$-linear space. Then $k$ happens to be infinite dimensional: if $k$ was finite dimensional then it would be finite (of finite cardinality), as $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ is a finite field. So $k$ would also be a finite *field*. But this is impossible, because a finite field is never algebraically closed.